# can not retrieve json object value postgresql 9.6

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
array_ json;
category_name text;
category_ json:='{"Maincategory":"Vehicle","Categoryname":"Car"}'::json;
BEGIN
category_name:=(SELECT category_  ->'Maincategory'::text) ;
array_:=(SELECT elements -> category_name FROM webuser.footable WHERE id=somenumber)::json;
raise notice '%',array_ ;
END
$$;


                             elements                       
                              (json)                    
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|{"Vehicle": [{"Car": 3}, {"Truck": 1}], "Office": [{"Printer": 3}, {"Desk": 8}]}     |
```

I have elements column and i want to retrieve vehicle array which is `([{"Car": 3}, {"Truck": 1}]` ) that will be stored in array_ variable. I get array_ always null. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`category_  ->'Maincategory'::text` will return `"Vehicle"`, while you need the value of the filed...

change `(SELECT category_  ->'Maincategory'::text)`

to

`(SELECT category_  ->>'Maincategory'::text)`, like here:

```
b=# DO
b-# $$
b$# DECLARE
b$# array_ json;
b$# category_name text;
b$# category_ json:='{"Maincategory":"Vehicle","Categoryname":"Car"}'::json;
b$# elements  json:= '{"Vehicle": [{"Car": 3}, {"Truck": 1}], "Office": [{"Printer": 3}, {"Desk": 8}]}';
b$# BEGIN
b$# category_name:=(SELECT category_ ->>'Maincategory'::text) ;
b$# raise info '%',(select elements->category_name);
b$# --array_:=(SELECT elements -> category_name FROM webuser.footable WHERE id=somenumber)::json;
b$# --raise notice '%',array_ ;
b$# END
b$# $$;
INFO:  [{"Car": 3}, {"Truck": 1}]
DO
```

Comment: that works but if i use a variable(in that case : category_name) instead of 'Vehicle' than it doesnt work.

Comment: @sommeguyy I updated the answer - mind `->` is different from `->>`